# Can't centre Listview Item when using OwnerDrawn

Tags: vb.net, listview

When trying to custom draw my coloumn headers and listview items, I was getting jagged text (not anti-aliased) which looked crappy.  I came across the following code snippet to render the text and display much more nicely - which works.  However, I can't work out how to centre my text in the column.  Currently, setting my flags to HorizontalCentre actually centres the text within the entire listview control.

```
Private Sub lsvOverdueCalls_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lsvOverdueCalls.DrawItem
    If e.Item.Selected AndAlso e.Item.ListView.Focused Then
        e.Item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight
        e.Item.ForeColor = e.Item.ListView.BackColor
    ElseIf e.Item.Selected AndAlso Not e.Item.ListView.Focused Then
        e.Item.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        e.Item.ForeColor = e.Item.ListView.ForeColor
    Else
        e.Item.BackColor = e.Item.ListView.BackColor
        e.Item.ForeColor = e.Item.ListView.ForeColor
    End If

    e.DrawBackground()

    ' Draw the header text.
    Dim rec As New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 2, e.Bounds.Width - 4, e.Bounds.Height - 4)
    Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis Or TextFormatFlags.ExpandTabs Or TextFormatFlags.SingleLine
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Text, e.Item.ListView.Font, rec, e.Item.ForeColor, flags)
End Sub
```

My result is this:
[image]

I need the Call Number (26155) to sit centre of the Call ID Column.

Comment: `e.Bounds` is the entire width.  What is the width of your Call ID column?

Comment: The width of the Call ID column is 80.  Can I reference the bounds of the column or do I need to hard code the values?  I have tried using e.Item.Bounds but I still get the same result.

Comment: If you give your columns a key, you can just reference the width: `listView1.Columns("callID").Width`, otherwise, index order `listView`.Columns(0).Width`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I have managed to use your comments to achieve what I need with some minor playing around.  Can you post as an answer so I can give you the credit.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.Bounds` is the entire width.  To get the width of your column, try referencing the Width property of the ListView column.

If you gave your columns keys, reference them by key:

```
listView1.Columns("callID").Width
```

or index:

```
listView1.Columns(0).Width
```

Then your drawing rectangle would look something like this:

```
Dim colWidth As Integer = listView1.Columns("callID").Width
Dim rec As New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, _
                         colWidth, e.Bounds.Height)
```

Comment: Thanks Lars.  Your answer was very helpful.  Not sure if I should start a new thread on this, but the last issue I have is when I hover over my SubItems, they vanish.  The first Item remains but the rest of the row disappears.

Comment: Doesn't matter....fixed via this thread [link](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/graphics-gdi/17696-custom-drawn-listview-issues.html)